# Convert epoch seconds to date

Tags: date-and-time

I have got the following datetime from an API: 1395401384298

I am guessing it is in epoch miliseconds time (it should be one day in 2014) How can i convert it into a more readable String? I have been looking into `DateString[]` (https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DateString.html) with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The epoch starts from jan 01 1970, so you can do:

```
to = AbsoluteTime[{1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.`}];

DateString[1395858190 + to]
```

> Wed 26 Mar 2014 18:23:10

From http://www.epochconverter.com/

> GMT: Wed, 26 Mar 2014 18:23:10 GMT

Answer (score 0):

It is in the very fa future :)
DateString[1395401384298]
"Tue 5 Jul 46118 23:38:18"

Adding a dot brings closer:
DateString[1395401384.298]
"Tue 21 Mar 1944 11:29:44"

So check the data you have received.
János

Comment: That is the wrong answer i am getting. The right answer is GMT: Fri, 21 Mar 2014 11:29:44 GMT (you can check it in http://www.epochconverter.com/ )